# error: expected type-specifier before ‘Number’

Tags: c++

I have attempted to figure out the error above but have come nowhere.  Every time I compiler I get the error:

`/home/duncan/Desktop/OOPS/dac80/json/parser.cpp: In function ‘Value* parseString(std::stringstream&)’:
    /home/duncan/Desktop/OOPS/dac80/json/parser.cpp:149:19: error: expected type-specifier before ‘String’
  Value* val = new String(name);`

I have verified that I am including the correct header file in the source files so that the compiler recognizes the file.  Below is the code concerning the error

Parser.cpp:

```html
#include "object_model.h"

Value* parseString(std::stringstream& in)
{ 
 std::string name("123");
 
 Value* val = new String(name);
 
 return val;
}
```

object_model.hpp:

```html
#ifndef OBJECTMODEL_H
#define OBJECTMODEL_H

#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

enum ValueType { Object = 0, Array = 1, String = 2, Number = 3, True = 4, False = 5, Null = 6};


class Value
{
 public:
  Value() {}
  virtual ValueType getType() = 0;
};


class String : public Value
{
 public:
  String(std::string content);
  ~String();
  
  std::string content;
  
  virtual ValueType getType();
};

#endif
```

object_model.cpp:

```html
#include "object_model.h"

String::String(std::string content)
{
 this->content = content;
}

String::~String()
{

}

ValueType String::getType()
{
 return (ValueType)2;
}
```

Another thing that I have noticed if that I change String to Text then the code compiles completely.  Not sure why but would the name String ever conflict with the std::string class?

Comment: No, it conflicts with your other `String` identifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What Chris means when he says "No, it conflicts with your other String identifier" is that your 'class String' clashes with the identifier 'String' from "enum ValueType { Object = 0, Array = 1, String = 2, Number = 3, True = 4, False = 5, Null = 6};", so what the compiler sees for

```
Value* val = new String(name);
```

is

```
Value* val = new 2(name);
```

Comment: Thanks!  That was the problem!